# Windows 8 WinRT app and phonegap

Tags: windows-8, cordova, windows-runtime

I want to read a SSL(CA) Certificate kept in my application bundle but the problem is Windows Store App does not include native C# files.

1)Is there a way to give Native C# support in a windows store application.?
2)How to write phone gap plugins for Windows 8?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/index.html....

Comment: @ManetiVinay for Win8

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html

Comment: @ManetiVinay windows 8 surface not phone

Comment: You are asking several questions, it might help to break them out and ask separately. Do you want to use certificates? (not a problem afaik http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2012/07/18/client-and-server-certificates-in-metro-style-apps.aspx , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/12/18/security-best-practices-for-building-windows-store-apps.aspx ), or do you want to make a plugin, and what do you mean by 'Native C#'?

Comment: @IrisClasson I want to read a certificate kept in my application package. I also want to use C# function to access camera etc in a Web app